# Hide element depending on select but load the value

Tags: jquery

I have this setup:

```
<select id="status" name="status">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="additional_information" class="hidden">
  Additional information
</div>
```

---

```
var val = $("#status option:selected").val();

if (val == '1') {
  $('#additional_information').removeClass('hidden');
} else {
  $('#additional_information').addClass('hidden');
}
```

When page is opened jQuery reads the value and shows or hides the hidden div.
But if I change the slect option it doesn't get the change anymore.

How to make it work so that it loads the value at page load and then to change it accordingly every time when user selects an option in select?

**[JSFIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/z00efajm/10/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I use the change event and trigger it onload too

The code is simplified using [toggleClass](https://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/)

```js
$(function() {
  $("#status").on("change", function() {
    // hide if this.value == 2 or use !=1 if there are more than 2 options
    $('#additional_information').toggleClass('hidden', this.value == 2); 
  }).change(); // trigger to hide or show on load
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="status" name="status">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="additional_information" class="hidden">
  Additional information
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `change` event:

```js
$('#status').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value == '1') {
    $('#additional_information').removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('#additional_information').addClass('hidden');
  }
}).change();
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="status" name="status">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="additional_information" class="hidden">
  Additional information
</div>
```

Comment: well you see that is the problem, it doesn't read the value....in your snippet the additional information is hidden on 1 selected and it should be shown...how to fix this?

Comment: @lewis4u, see now. I've updated the answer. Had to change to get the current value using `this.value`

Comment: Are you just loading the page with class="hidden" on? If so, either trigger a change or remove it

Comment: @mplungjan, `.toggleClass( className, state )`

Comment: @Satpal yes - I have it the correct way around in my answer

Comment: yes it works now....thank you...but other 2 answers are more elegant and now i don't know what to do....all of you are right...there are 1000 ways to Rome

Comment: @lewis4u, you just accept the one you think it better fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Add your code to separated function Then call it on `ready` and on `change` like :

```js
$(function(){
  //For the first load
  show_hide();

  //For the user change on the status select
  $('#status').on('change', show_hide);
})

function show_hide(){
  var val = $("#status option:selected").val();

  if (val == '1') {
    $('#additional_information').removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('#additional_information').addClass('hidden');
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id='status'>
  <option value='1'>With additional information</option>
  <option value='2'>Without additional information</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<div id="additional_information">
  Additional information
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have an event handler, like this:

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z00efajm/16/)

Javascript:

```
$("#status").on("change", function() {
  $('#additional_information').toggleClass('hidden', this.value != 1);

});
$("#status").trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 1):

To have it detect when the page loads, as well as when it changes, add the `.change()` event handler and manually trigger it when the page loads:

```
$("#status").change(function() {
  var val = $("#status option:selected").val();
  if (val == '1') {
    $('#additional_information').removeClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('#additional_information').addClass('hidden');
  }
}).change()
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z00efajm/14/)**

Comment: this is the most elegant solution!

Comment: @mplungjan your answer doesn't work at all as it should!

Comment: I reversed the test. Now it does

Comment: @lewis4u Totally up to you. Whichever answer helped you the most should be accepted.